# Unable to Connect to SQL Server 2014 SP2 using the SQL Native Client 10

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, odbc, sql-server-2014

Attempting to connect using the SQL Server Native Client 10.0 Results in the below error:
Client Unable to establish connection
Shared Memory Provider: No Process is on the other end of the pipe.

Forcing the connection to use TCP just changes the error to a TCP error with similar contents

Using the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 works fine, unfortunately the application I am trying to connect with does not give me that option as the built in SSIS Packages were built for SQL Server 2008.

I have never had this issue before with the same basic deployment scenario (SQL Server 2014 and Windows Server 2012 R2)

I have been googling the issue but all the issues I can find relate to general connection issues, not ones that only occur with the Native Client 10.0. I checked the listed solutions like checking the protocols are enabled, firewalls and services are running regardless and everything appears configured correctly which explains why the Native Client 11 works

No errors show up in Windows or SQL Event logs when this happens

I have also updated to the latest release of the SQL Native Client which has not helped

The same problem occurs no matter what software I initiate the connection from (e.g. SSAS, ODBC) nor what source computer (Local or Remote)

Has anyone else seen this or a similar issue before?

Comment: Is sql browser running?  this posts suggests that as a reason while SQLNCLI10 wouldn't connect.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eb45b8f8-a858-4160-9441-818cbb099697/sql-native-client-sqlncli10-connect-to-sql-server-2012?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: Yes, the SQL Browser is running.

Comment: TLS 1.2 issue?  is TLS 1.0/SSL disabled on the server?  What file version of the SQLNCLI10 do you have?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: Thanks StrayCatDBA, I actually found the same solution about 10 minutes ago! It seems sleeping on the problem helped. This thread https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1810025-3411-1.aspx over at SQLServerCentral led me to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the issue for this one, the owners of this server have removed all but TLS 1.2/AES encryption which isn't supported by the SQL Native Client 10.0

I was able to download an on-request hotfix from the below link which resolved the issue for me.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

If you need to determine which ciphers are available for a server you can check the registry or use a tool like IISCrypto https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto